# Recursive OR statement SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at creating a relatively simple insert statement that inserts a new record if there are any changes to a table. Issue i have is there are over 600 columns that would need to be checked.

More details: the main reporting table is updated every 15 minutes from the front end application using a SQL process to push the changes, however it over-writes the data and doesn't maintain a change log. I have no control over any of this.

Second table (my table) is a DWH table, which will create an audit of changes. So I use an inner join where `t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo and t1.Field1 <> t.2Field1` then add an OR and add the next field `t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo and t1.Field2 <> t.2Field2` .

Is there a better way to get the desired result given the number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different approach.

Create a trigger on the main table for update and delete.
This trigger copies the data which is already in the table to your dwh table before the data has changed.

```
create Trigger [nameupdate] on [yourtable] after update
as
insert into [dwh]
select 
      getdate() as [ChangeDate]
      ,'update' as [Action]
      ,SYSTEM_USER as [User]
      ,d.[ID]
      ,d.[...]
 from deleted d 
GO
```

same for delete

```
create Trigger [namedelete] on [yourtable] after delete
[...]
```

my dwh table has 3 additional columns for tracking and contains all columns from main table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dwh](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary key,
    [ChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [User] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [...]
```

Comment: That could be a good way forward, only issue with that is i would need to do a insert trigger as well, but the data rebuilds every night.. so it would create all the data again every night. can you schedule triggers to only run during certain hours!?!

Comment: Ignore me. You can! This is perfect

Comment: You can also create a insert trigger of curse. You can compare the new (inserted table) and old data (deleted table) in every trigger. you can also compare to the dwh table. that's just magic in the trigger's insert sql.